# Windows Phone 7 - Camera Flash App Not Functioning

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In attempting to follow the instructions here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202949.aspx I have coded a very simple WP7 app to turn on the camera flash. Everything appears to work, except....the flash doesn't activate.

My phone is Samsung SGH-I917 (latest OS update), I am using the WP7 SDK 7.1, I've checked that the flash of my camera actually does work. I have also checked to make sure the following is in the WMAppManifest.xml file.

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
```

The `MessageBox` use you see in my code below, indicates that the camera object has been initialized properly, the flashmode is supported and the `FlashMode.On` has been set. Yet...no flash will actually turn on. What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    PhotoCamera cam;        

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        cam = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
        cam.Initialized += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(cam_Initialized);
        cam.CaptureCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(cam_CaptureCompleted);
        cam.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureImageAvailable);
        cam.CaptureThumbnailAvailable += new EventHandler<ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureThumbnailAvailable);
        viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam);
    }

    void cam_CaptureThumbnailAvailable(object sender, ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        return;
    }

    void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        return;
    }

    void cam_CaptureCompleted(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        return;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cam != null)
        {
            cam.Dispose();
            cam.Initialized -= cam_Initialized;
            cam.CaptureCompleted -= cam_CaptureCompleted;
            cam.CaptureImageAvailable -= cam_CaptureImageAvailable;
            cam.CaptureThumbnailAvailable -= cam_CaptureThumbnailAvailable;
        }
    }

    void cam_Initialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cam Init, FlashMode.On Supported?: " + cam.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.On).ToString());
        });

        return;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(cam.FlashMode == FlashMode.On)
            cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
        else
            cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cam.FlashMode.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="FlashLite" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" />
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Width="200" Height="100" Content="Flash" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;
```

only indicates that the flash will be activated when capturing the image.

That is achieved by doing

```
cam.CaptureImage();
```

EDIT : If you only want to trigger the flash, you can just call `cam.Focus();`

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. So if I want to make a "flashlight" app to keep the flash on all the time, I guess I need to find a way to constantly call `CaptureImage();`?

Comment: I think that `cam.Focus();` also triggers the flash

Comment: Nice, thank you for the info. Will check tonight how it works.

Comment: cam.Focus() triggers the flash. As lots of people that wanted to create a LED flashlight have found out there is no way to keep the LED on for more than 1-2 seconds. You can continuously call focus() or even start a new focus in the AutofocusCompleted event, but all you get is a blinking flash. To get a steady flash you have to look at VideoCaptureDevice.

Comment: @danglund - Yes, I figured this out as well a few days ago. You could add that answer to here and I will upvote. It's an important thing to note.