# Reduce blink windows phone 7 flash

Tags: windows-phone-7

What is the best approach to set a Windows Phone 7 led to torch mode? I have used http://www.locked.nl/wp7-flashlight-getting-started but using reflection and/or the `VideoCaptureDevice` is not allowed. (only works on dev phone)

I have used the AutoFocusCompleted event and have tried a task (taskfactory.new) and regular task. My latest attempt uses the `DispatcherTimer`.

So what is the best approach to keep calling `Focus` and/or `FocusAtPoint` to minimize the blinking and get the closest to a constant light.

[Windows Phone 7 - Camera Flash App Not Functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495426/windows-phone-7-camera-flash-app-not-functioning)

Comment: Calling focus in small fractions would not let the flash behave as a continues lamp. Wp7 exposes only a single way to achieve it and that is with the link you provided. I too tried for it in one of my apps, But in vain.